# Polars: Addressing "The predicate passed to 'LazyFrame.filter' expanded to multiple expressions"

Tags: python-polars

From Polars 0.16.11 the following filter statement raises an exception with the following error message:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'lag1':[0,1,None],'lag2':[0,None,2]})
df.filter(pl.col('^lag.*$').is_not_null())

ComputeError: The predicate passed to 'LazyFrame.filter' expanded to multiple expressions:

    col("lag1").is_not_null().any(),
    col("lag2").is_not_null().any(),
This is ambiguous. Try to combine the predicates with the 'all' or `any' expression.
```

How can I address it to filter rows where any of the lag columns are `null`?

Answer (score 2):

As @lxlxlx rightfully mentioned, as of today's Polars API, the correct way to evaluate against a predicate containing multiple Boolean expressions is either by using:

- [`pl.all_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal) (for bitwise AND horizontally across expressions)
- [`pl.any_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html) (for bitwise AND horizontally across expressions).

Answer (score 0):

To filter rows where any of the lag columns are `null` use the `pl.all` function:

```py
df.filter(pl.all(pl.col('^lag.*$').is_not_null()))
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ lag1 ┆ lag2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 0    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Hi @braaannigan, maybe there's a typo in the code? to filter where any columns are null, isn't the right code df.filter(~pl.all(pl.col('^lag.*$').is_not_null())) or df.filter(pl.any(pl.col('^lag.*$').is_null())) ?

Comment: Correct @Luca, I've updated this now

Comment: A note to latecomers like me. Until today(0.19.0+), the API has changed to `pl.all_horizontal`, `pl.any_horizontal`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017948/how-to-filter-duplicates-based-on-multiple-columns-in-polars and polars doc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.select(['lag1', 'lag2']).filter(pl.any(pl.col('*').is_null()))
```