# Rust Polars - Selecting columns after applying filter (on rows) of a DataFrame

Tags: rust, rust-polars

This used to be working until upgraded to latest Polars. The `df` Dataframe has more than 2 columns,  `CP` and `CP` are 2 of them. The intent here is to select column `CK` and `CP` for rows that are greater than value `0`.

```
let e11_filter = df
    .lazy()
    .filter(cols(["CK", "CP"]).gt(lit(0)))
    .collect()?;
```

The error is as below.

```
Error: ComputeError(ErrString("The predicate passed to 'LazyFrame.filter' expanded to multiple expressions:

    [(col(\"CK\")) > (0)],
    [(col(\"CP\")) > (0)],
This is ambiguous. Try to combine the predicates with the 'all_exprs' or 'any_exprs' expression.

Error originated just after this operation:
DF [\"W\", \"Dataset\", \"MD\", \"CK\"]; PROJECT */8 COLUMNS; SELECTION: \"None\""))
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75663995/polars-addressing-the-predicate-passed-to-lazyframe-filter-expanded-to-multi), but it is Python version.

Comment: Do you want rows which have both CK > 0 and CP > 0 or either one of them > 0?

Comment: Both rows in CK and CP are greater than 0, not either.

Comment: Can you try `.filter(all_exprs(cols(["CK", "CP"]).gt(lit(0))))`? https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.all_exprs.html

Comment: Tried that. Error ```error[E0277]: the trait bound 'Expr: AsRef<[Expr]> is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:50:27
     |
50   |         .filter(all_exprs(cols(["CK", "CP"]).gt(lit(0))))
     |                 --------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait 'AsRef<[Expr]>' is not implemented for 'Expr'
     |                 |
     |                 required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
note: required by a bound in 'polars::prelude::all_exprs'```

Comment: Here is part of my Cargo.toml ```polars = {version = "*", features =["lazy", "ndarray"]}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make the call unambiguous by applying the "greater than 0" filter on each column explicitly and combining these resulting column filters with the [`and`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.and) operation:

```
let e11_filter = df
    .lazy()
    .filter(col("CK").gt(lit(0)).and(col("CP").gt(lit(0))))
    .collect()
    .unwrap();
```

[Rustexplorer.](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Apolars%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%220.29.0%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22lazy%22%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0Ause%20polars%3A%3Aprelude%3A%3A*%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20df%20%3D%20df!%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22CK%22%20%3D%3E%20%5B-1%2C%201%2C%20-1%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22CP%22%20%3D%3E%20%5B-1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20e11_filter%20%3D%20df%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.lazy()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.filter(col(%22CK%22).gt(lit(0)).and(col(%22CP%22).gt(lit(0))))%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Be11_filter%3A%3F%7D%22)%3B%0A%7D)

---

Update: I got the [`all_exprs`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.all_exprs.html) version Dogbert suggested to work, which is more in line with the answer of the Python version you've linked:

```
let e11_filter = df
    .lazy()
    .filter(all_exprs([cols(["CK", "CP"]).gt(lit(0))]))
    .collect()
    .unwrap();
```

[Rustexplorer.](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Apolars%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%220.29.0%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22lazy%22%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0Ause%20polars%3A%3Aprelude%3A%3A*%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20df%20%3D%20df!%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22CK%22%20%3D%3E%20%5B-1%2C%201%2C%20-1%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22CP%22%20%3D%3E%20%5B-1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20e11_filter%20%3D%20df%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.lazy()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.filter(all_exprs(%5Bcols(%5B%22CK%22%2C%20%22CP%22%5D).gt(lit(0))%5D))%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Be11_filter%3A%3F%7D%22)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks Jonas & Dogbert. It solved the issues.